psql - compared reload time to saving time of pg_hba.conf
I once saw a query which compared the save time of pg_hba.conf with the latest reload time of the cluster in order to check whether all existing entries should be effective yet, or not.
stupid me failed to save that thing. Can anybody help me out?

I don't think you can find out the last reload time in PostgreSQL, but maybe I am missing something.

you can. I am certain that there is some function to get the reload time. I used it. Basically you call a function to get the reload time, you call a function to get the adjust time of pg_hba.conf and compare those 2 timestamps to each other

seems I just did not dig deep enough
SELECT pg_conf_load_time() > modification FROM pg_stat_file('pg_hba.conf') ;

Edit:
I actually just earned that this is even more universal
SELECT pg_conf_load_time() > modification  FROM pg_stat_file( current_setting('hba_file') ) ;
(because it finds pg_hba_files not located in the data_directory also)

Great! I learned something.
